# No such file or directory error mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Im trying to make a TextEdit UTF-8 file executable but the command
`chmod +x /path/to/script/filename.sh` does not seem to work for me.
The error is:
`chmod: /path/to/script/filename.sh: No such file or directory`

Im not sure what this means or why it is happening. The file's path is iCloud Drive > TextEdit > filename.sh

Thanks

Edit: This is my first post and it got downvoted. I believe that it is clear but does not show signs of effort... I did do research.

On a similar question, they advised to access it using the cp command. So I moved the file to desktop and tried accessing it using the command but this did not work either: It gave the same error.

Secondly, other answers said to use a different command, such as first marking the file as executable using `chmod +x filename.sh` and then executing it using `./filename.sh`; however, this attempt was fruitless yet again.

So, I seek for aid here...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing it from right click - get info - scroll down to the sharing & permissions section.

After all iCloud drive is not supposed to be a directory path. There is another path as the physical location of your file

Comment: I went to sharing and permissions and changed all of them to read and write, but this still did not work when I typed the command into terminal; it gave the same error